# How to replace all 11 consecutive number in a nvarchar field with asterisk in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a textarea on the view which saves the input in an nvarchar(max) field.  The users wrote an 11 number digit which is sensitive information on the textarea which  they should not have.  I was asked to replace the 11 consecutive number with ***********.

```
Sample Dataset

Id    Details
1     Id: 03948518231 
      ddk asd
2     ed 99 93482019393 ex

3     ehhdg g#3  85291293841 ldd
```

Result after update:

```
Id    Details
1     Id: *********** 
      ddk asd
2     ed 99 *********** ex

3     ehhdg g#3  *********** ldd
```

Something like this:

Update InfoTable SET Details=DetailsWithout11ConsecutiveNumbers

Comment: You really need regex replace to handle this problem gracefully.  But since SQL Server doesn't have this support built in, you will need to find a library or maybe write a UDF.

Comment: Do you want to hide this at the actual data level (permanently change data) or just when queried for display?

Comment: You are asking about *data masking*, not replacing characters. First of all, SQL Server 2017 provides [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking). If that's not enough or available, you should probably mask the data *before* storing it in the database. T-SQL isn't great in string manipulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stuff` and `patindex`. But be aware that it will replace first occurrence of 11 consecutive numbers

```
declare @InfoTable table (
    Details varchar(40)
)

insert into @InfoTable
values ('Id: 03948518231 ')
, ('ed 99 93482019393 ex')
, ('ehhdg g#3  85291293841 ldd')

update @InfoTable
set Details = stuff(Details, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Details), 11, '***********')
where
    patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Details) > 0

select * from @InfoTable
```

Comment: Nice answer, and I didn't know that PATINDEX supports limited regex ability.

Comment: Looks interesting. Trying.

Comment: Great one, Thumb!

Comment: @JoseCarlosBalantakbo, added `where` clause to remove rows where is no sensitive information

Comment: Worked perfect!

Comment: WHERE Details like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' would probably work better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PATINDEX but you also need to handle the case where you no sensitive values

```
DECLARE @Mytable table (ID tinyint NOT NULL, Details nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)
INSERT @Mytable VALUES 
    (1, 'Id: 03948518231 ddk asd'), 
    (2, 'ed 99 93482019393 ex'), 
    (3, 'ehhdg g#3  85291293841 ldd'), 
    (4, 'nothing secret here');

SELECT
    ID, 
    CASE WHEN X.SensitiveStart > 0 THEN STUFF(Details, X.SensitiveStart, 11, '***********') ELSE X.Details END
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        ID, Details, 
        SensitiveStart = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Details)
    FROM
        @Mytable
    ) X
```

If you have multiple sensitive values

```
DECLARE @Mytable table (ID tinyint NOT NULL, Details nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)
INSERT @Mytable VALUES 
    (1, 'Id: 03948518231 ddk asd'), 
    (2, 'ed 99 93482019393 ex'), 
    (3, 'ehhdg g#3  85291293841 ldd'), 
    (4, 'nothing secret here'), 
    (5, 'two 93482019393 sensitive 85291293841 values');

WITH MultipleSecretValue AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, 
        CASE WHEN X.SensitiveStart > 0 THEN STUFF(Details, X.SensitiveStart, 11, '***********') ELSE X.Details END AS Details,
        0 AS Level
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            ID, Details, 
            SensitiveStart = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Details)
        FROM
            @Mytable
        ) X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID, 
        STUFF(Details, X.SensitiveStart, 11, '***********'),
        Level + 1
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            ID, Details, 
            SensitiveStart = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Details),
            Level
        FROM
            MultipleSecretValue
        ) X 
    WHERE
        SensitiveStart > 0
)
SELECT
    X.ID, X.Details
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID ORDER BY m.Level DESC),
        m.ID,
        m.Details
    FROM 
        MultipleSecretValue m
    ) X
WHERE
    X.rn = 1
```

Comment: Works too btw.  Thank you.